# Date Headings not in correct location

Tags: php, html

I have a group of article titles with dates. The titles populate 3 columns.  At the beginning of each date, March 10, 2017 for example, I would like to have the date appear at the top. Then for March 9, 2017, I'd like to have that date appear at the beginning of the March 9, 2017 Article Titles with a separation line between the dates and so on.

The code I have is giving me all the heading dates at the top instead of in the correct heading locations.  I think the problem is I'm not handling the 2 if statements correctly.  You can see how it currently looks at http://www.althedge.xyz/searchold2.php

I want it to look like this:

03/10/2017...................................................................................................................................
Article 1-03/10/17..........Article2-03/10/17.............Article3-03-10-17

Article 4-03/10/17..........Article5-03/10/17...............................

---

03/09/2017.........................................................................................................................................
Article 1-03/09/17..........Article2-03/09/17.............Article3-03-09-17

Article 4-03/09/17..........Article5-03/09/17.............Articel6-03-09-17

Article 7-03/09/17

---

03/08/2017....................................................................................................................................
Article 1-03/08/17..........Article2-03/08/2017

Could someone show me how to put the date headings where I want them?  Thanks

```
  <?php

    // Database Settings 
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_PORT', '*****');
    define('DB_USER', '*****');
    define('DB_PASS', '*****');
    define('DB_NAME', '******');

    // Connection to Database
    $database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
    $sql = 'SELECT * '
            . ' FROM crypto ORDER BY Date DESC, Number DESC';
    $resultSet = $database->query($sql); 
    $currentDate = false; 

    // set up loop counter 
    $col_count = 0; 

    // start table and first tr 
    echo '<table border="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;"><tr>'; 

    while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
       // if you have output 3 cols then end tr and start a new one 
       if ($col_count == 3) { 
          echo '</tr><tr>'; 
          //  and reset the col count 
          $col_count = 0; 

    if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
     echo
     $row['Date'] ;
    $currentDate = $row['Date'];  
    }


       } 
       // always output the td 
       echo '<td>' . $row['Article'] . $row['Date'] . '</td>'; 
      // and count the column 
      $col_count++; 
    } 

    // then close off the last row and the table 
    echo '</tr></table>';  


    ?>
```

Comment: can you please show your expected outcome? how it need to look like?

Comment: Hi, I added the way I want it to look.  Appreciate you looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just do something like this.

```
echo '<table border="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
<tr><th>heading1</th><th>heading2</th><th>heading3</th></tr><tr>'; 

while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) { 
   // if you have output 3 cols then end tr and start a new one 
   if ($col_count % 3) { 
      echo '</tr><tr>'; 
   }

if ($row['Date'] != $currentDate){
 echo
 $row['Date'] ;
$currentDate = $row['Date'];  
}

   // always output the td 
   echo '<td>' . $row['Article'] . $row['Date'] . '</td>'; 
  // and count the column 
  $col_count++; 
} 

// then close off the last row and the table 
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: That's not what I wanted.   All that did was put headings above each column.  Thanks though